# What's the name for the technique where a portrait-oriented image is filled-out to a landscape one with a scaled-up blurred version of the same image?

Tags: photo-editing, technique, editing

It is very common nowadays, specially with smartphone videos and photos. It consists of adding the same picture zoomed in the background, to turn a portrait image into a landscape one, as seen below. I'm sure it's super obvious but I've googled it without success.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The [Cloudinary page](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/206112219-How-to-transform-a-portrait-image-to-landscape-by-adding-blurry-padding) where it looks like you found the pictures suggests "blurry padding". Were you looking for something else?

Comment: Also, there's not necessarily a concise name for everything...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Banding the sides of an image is called [*pillarboxing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillarbox) (as opposed to banding the top and bottom, i.e., letterboxing). Wikipedia's page refers to the technique you describe as "stylized pillarboxing" or "echo pillarboxing".